# Is every finite CW complex is homotopic to simplicial complex?

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff, cw-complexes

Is every finite CW complex is homotopy equivalent to a simplicial complex?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is theorem 2C.5 p.182 from Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*:

> Every CW complex X is homotopy equivalent to a simplicial complex,
>   which can be chosen to be of the same dimension as X, finite if X is
>   finite, and countable if X is countable.