# Homotypy types of Simplicial Complexes vs $\Delta$-Complexes vs CW Complexes

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-complex

I want to compare diferences between *homotopy types* of
simplicial complexes, $\Delta$-complexes and CW-complexes.
(to avoid confusions I'm using the definitions, notations und
constructions of simplicial complexes and $\Delta$-complexes
from Greg Friedman's An elementary illustrated  [Introduction to simplicial sets](https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.4221)

In [this excellent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1528061) Eric Wolfsey explaines the fundamental differences
between the construction of simplicial complexes, $\Delta$-complexes
and CW-complexes. The key point is the presence of different levels of
restrictivity of glueing maps of the boundary of the simplices.

Therefore we have proper inclusions of classes

$$ \text{simplicial complexes } \subset \Delta \text{-complexes} 
\subset \text{CW-complexes}  $$

Here I would like to discuss how far these classes differ from each other
as on level of *homotopy types*. Let $A$ some interesting class of topological spaces, eg simplicial complexes or CGHS (compactly generated Hausdorff spaces). I introduce the non standard
notation

$$\text{Ho(certain class of topol. spaces A)}:=
\{X \text{ top. space } \ \vert \ \text{ there exist a space } Y \in A 
\text{ such that } X \simeq Y \}  $$

The natural question is, if there is something known about inclusion
relations between $ \text{Ho(simplicial complexes) }, 
\text{Ho(} \Delta \text{-complexes)} $ and
$\text{Ho(CW complexes) }$?

As Eric Wolfsey pointed out in his answer, the inclusion
$ \text{simplicial complexes } \subset \Delta \text{-complexes} $ is
proper, since there exist $\Delta$-complexes which are not constructable
as simplicial complexes and simular of the CW-complexes, since $\Delta$-complexes allow tremendously more freedom degrees in glueing procedure. By same reason, the CW-complexes form a bigger class that the $\Delta$-complexes.

But what is known about eg the inclusion $ \text{Ho(simplicial complexes) } \subset 
\text{Ho(} \Delta \text{-complexes)} $ between the sets of homotopy types?

Comment: Every CW complex has the homotopy type of a simplicial complex. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/941080/2941

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip: wow that's wonderful! Thank you!